# add timing function to css slider

Tags: html, css

Have been trying to get my head around this for days but need some assistance from you css gurus!

I have a pure css slider that uses some controls which is great. The issue is that I want the slider to also move automatically like a timings function. I was trying to do it using keyframes but had no luck.

How would this be possible?

HTML:

```
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">

    <div class="sliderPagination">
        <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
        <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
        <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
        <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="next control">
        <label for="slider_1" class="numb1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
        <label for="slider_2" class="numb2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
        <label for="slider_3" class="numb3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
        <label for="slider_4" class="numb4"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="previous control">
        <label for="slider_1" class="numb1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
        <label for="slider_2" class="numb2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
        <label for="slider_3" class="numb3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
        <label for="slider_4" class="numb4"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
    </div>


    <div class="slider slide1">

    </div>
    <div class="slider slide2">

    </div>
    <div class="slider slide3">

    </div>
    <div class="slider slide4">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/* SLIDER WRAPPER */
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 }
 .mainSlider.wrapper {
  border-bottom: solid 6px #cc2027;
  height: 900px;
  height: 100vh;
 }


  /* SLIDER */
  .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;

  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  }

  .slider > * {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1s;
  }


   /* CONTROLS */ 
   .control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  z-index: 55;
  }
  .control label {
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
  }
  .control label:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .next {
   right: 1%;
  }
  .previous {
  left: 1%;
  }
  .sliderPagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  right: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 50;
  }
  .sliderPagination label {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #959595;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
  }

  .slide-radio1:checked ~ .next .numb2, 
  .slide-radio2:checked ~ .next .numb3, 
  .slide-radio3:checked ~ .next .numb4, 
  .slide-radio2:checked ~ .previous .numb1, 
  .slide-radio3:checked ~ .previous .numb2, 
  .slide-radio4:checked ~ .previous .numb3 {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1
  }


   /* ACTIVE */
  .slide-radio1:checked ~ .sliderPagination .page1, 
  .slide-radio2:checked ~ .sliderPagination .page2, 
  .slide-radio3:checked ~ .sliderPagination .page3, 
  .slide-radio4:checked ~ .sliderPagination .page4 {
  background: #cc2027;
  }

        /* SLIDER ANIMATION */
    .slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    .slide-radio2:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .slide-radio3:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    .slide-radio4:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
  transform: translateX(-300%);
    }

    .slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide1 h1, 
    .slide-radio2:checked ~ .slide2 h1, 
    .slide-radio3:checked ~ .slide3 h1, 
    .slide-radio4:checked ~ .slide4 h1,
    .slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide1 p, 
    .slide-radio2:checked ~ .slide2 p, 
    .slide-radio3:checked ~ .slide3 p, 
    .slide-radio4:checked ~ .slide4 p,
    .slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide1 .button, 
    .slide-radio2:checked ~ .slide2 .button, 
    .slide-radio3:checked ~ .slide3 .button, 
    .slide-radio4:checked ~ .slide4 .button {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: The problem here would be that a set of keyframes would overrule the current CSS transitions you've put in place, I think.